# Selecting 4 groups and sorting by a time field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small database with highschool football game scores where users can text a score in.

I need to find what the final score was at the end of each quarter

I am a little confused in how to do this given the data:

SCORE TABLE

```
create table FINAL_score

    ( scoreID varchar2(10) primary key,

    gameID varchar2(5) REFERENCES FINAL_game(gameID),

    userID varchar2(5) REFERENCES FINAL_user(userID),

    curtime timestamp,

    qtr number(1),

    hscore number(2) not null,

    ascore number(2) not null);


insert into FINAL_score values ('s001', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 02:10:00', 1, 7, 3);

insert into FINAL_score values ('s002', 'g001', 'u002', '10-DEC-12 02:12:00', 1, 7, 3);

insert into FINAL_score values ('s003', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 02:15:00', 1, 7, 10);

insert into FINAL_score values ('s004', 'g001', 'u002', '10-DEC-12 02:28:00', 2, 14, 13);

insert into FINAL_score values ('s005', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 02:30:00', 2, 14, 16);

insert into FINAL_score values ('s006', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 02:55:00', 3, 14, 19);

insert into FINAL_score values ('s007', 'g001', 'u002', '10-DEC-12 02:57:00', 3, 14, 16);

insert into FINAL_score values ('s008', 'g001', 'u001', '10-DEC-12 03:15:00', 4, 17, 26);

insert into FINAL_score values ('s009', 'g001', 'u002', '10-DEC-12 03:30:00', 4, 20, 29);
```

I'm thinking I'll need to use a subquery but I just don't know how to implement it

```
select hscore, ascore
from FINAL_score
where (....)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please show the desired result of query for your example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scores are actually monotonically increasing through the game (they only go up, not down).  So, you can take a shortcut and do:

```
select gameid, qtr, max(hscore), max(ascore)
from final_score
group by gameid
```

Answer (score 1):

The get the last record sent in for every game, do this:

```
select hscore, ascore
from (select * from FINAL_score 
      order by curtime desc) x
group by gameId;
```

For a specific game, add a where clause to this:

```
select hscore, ascore
from (select * from FINAL_score 
      where gameId = ?
      order by curtime desc) x
group by gameId;
```

Note that this is a mysql-only solution.